# Best known bounds on (border) ranks of small matrix multiplication tensors?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, na.numerical-analysis

The $(m,n,p)$-matrix multiplication tensor is a representation of the bilinear map $T\colon\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\times\mathbb{R}^{n\times p}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$ given by $T(A,B)=AB$. Any low-rank decomposition of this tensor leads to a faster-than-naive matrix multiplication algorithm (à la [the Strassen algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm)). Actually, to get a fast algorithm, it suffices for arbitrarily small perturbations of this tensor to have low rank; the minimum of such ranks is called the border rank.

**Where can I find a recent table of the best known upper and lower bounds on the rank and border rank of the $(m,n,p)$-matrix multiplication tensor for moderately small values of $m$, $n$ and $p$?**

Slide 24 [here](http://www.ens-lyon.fr/LIP/MC2/data/uploads/slidesmarkusblaser.pdf) is close to what I want, though I would prefer explicit citations and larger $m$, $n$ and $p$.

[Here's a related question that focuses on the $(3,3,3)$ case.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151058/best-known-bounds-on-tensor-rank-of-matrix-multiplication-of-3%C3%973-matrices)

Comment: Have you already looked into the book: *Tensors: geometry and applications* by Landsberg?

Comment: @Survit - I've looked online, but the links I found only provide limited views. While I haven't found what I'm looking for, I did find a drawing of a pickle held to someone's head: http://www.ams.org/books/gsm/128/gsm128-endmatter.pdf#page=19

Comment: Being completely not a specialist in this field I nevertheless suggest that I know a person who must know the exact answer to your question.
His personal page is http://spring.inm.ras.ru/osel/ (Ivan Oseledets) and one of his main research topics (together with E.E. Tyrtyshnikov) are so called tensor train approximations which are something closely related to low-rank approximations for tensors.
So, probably you could ask the professor.

Answer (score 3):

There are upper bounds collections in [1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2010.12.012) and [2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1134/S0965542513120129).

The best known lower bounds for (3,3,3) is $R \geq 19$ by Bläser ([3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0885-064X(02)00007-9)), for (2,2,m) is $R \geq 3m + 2$ by Alekseev ([4](http://cheb.tsput.ru/attachments/714_tom16_v4_Alekseev.pdf), in Russian), and general lower bounds in [5](http://dx.doi.org/10.4086/toc.2015.v011a011) and  [6](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6320v2)

[1](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.tcs.2010.12.012) C.-E. Drevet, Md. Nazrul Islam, and É. Schost. "Optimization techniques for small matrix multiplication." Theor. Comp. Sci. 412(22) (2011), pp. 2219-2236.

[2](http://dx.doi.org/10.1134/S0965542513120129) A. V. Smirnov. "The bilinear complexity and practical algorithms for matrix multiplication." Comput. Math. and Math. Physics 53(12) (2013), pp. 1781-1795.

[3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0885-064X(02)00007-9) M. Bläser. "On the complexity of the multiplication of matrices of small formats." J. of Complexity 19(1) (2003), pp. 43-60.

[4](http://cheb.tsput.ru/attachments/714_tom16_v4_Alekseev.pdf) V. B. Alekseev "On bilinear complexity of multiplication of $m \times 2$ and $2 \times 2$ matrices" Chebyshevsky Sbornik 16(4) (2015), pp. 11-27 [in Russian]

[5](http://dx.doi.org/10.4086/toc.2015.v011a011) J.M. Landsberg, G. Ottaviani "New Lower Bounds for the Border Rank of Matrix Multiplication" Theory of Computing 11, 2015

[6](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6320v2) A. Massarenti, E. Ravioli "On the rank of $n\times n$ matrix multiplication", arXiv:1211.6320v2 [corrected version of a journal paper in Lin. Alg. Appl.]

Answer (score 3):

There is a table at http://cristal.univ-lille.fr/~sedoglav/FMM/ that (try to) gather such bounds

Comment: It is considered good practice here to disclose it when you link to your own website. Please add it explicitly to your answer.

Comment: It is also good to summarize the content for the case something happens to the link.